# How to print sum of digits for a Python integer?

Tags: python

Consider the following input prompt. I want to output the sum of digits that are inputted.

Example:

```
two_digit_number = input("Type a two digit number: ") 39
# program should print 12 (3 + 9) on the next line
```

If I input 39, I want to output 12 (3 + 9). How do I do this?

Comment: Can you show your effort? Also please mention where you got stuck

Comment: If always two digits `ans = (two_digit_number % 10) + (two_digit_number // 10)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum()`, transforming each digit to an integer:

```py
num = input("Enter a two digit number: ")
print(sum(int(digit) for digit in num))
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this:

```
numbers = list(input("Enter number: "))
print(sum(list(map(int, numbers))))
```

1. Read digits with input as a whole number of string type
2. split them with `list()` in characters in a list
3. use `map()` to convert type to int in a list
4. with `sum()` you're done.. just `print()`

Beware of invalid entries! "hundred" or "1 234 567"

Answer (score -1):

This is one of the many ways for it.

```py
    value = 39 # it is your input
    
    value_string = str(value)
    
    total = 0
    for digit in value_string:
        total += int(digit)
    
    print(total)
```

new version according to need mentioned in comment:

```py
    value = 39
    
    value_string = str(value)
    
    total = 0
    digit_list = []
    for digit in value_string:
        total += int(digit)
        digit_list.append(digit)
    
    print(" + ".join(digit_list))
    
    print(total)
```

Comment: no. its not working.  input 39 . sum = 12 . its ok. but it showing direct 12 . i want to show 3+9 first. then showing result.

Comment: It wasn't mentioned on the question. If you want like that, you can save every digit in variables or all in a list in the for loop, then you can print them before printing the sum at the end.

Answer (score -1):

you can achieve that like this:

```
a = input("Type a two digit number: ")
b = list(a)
print(int(b[0])+int(b[1]))
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Answer (score -1):

```
n = (int(input("Enter the two digit number\n")))
n = str(n)
p = int(n[0])+int(n[1])
print(p)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do that as follows:

```
two_digit_number = input("Type a two digit number: ") 
digits = two_digit_number.split("+")
print("sum = ", int(digits[0])+int(digits[1]))
```

Explanation:

1. first read the input (ex: 1+1)
2. then use `split()` to separate the input statement into the strings of the input digits only
3. then use `int()` to cast the digit from `string` to `int`

Comment: A two digit number is a number between 10 and 99. 1+1 is two numbers separated by an operator